# Wordpress Custom Posts

Tags: wordpress-theming

I'm having a serious problem with custom post types in Wordpress. I made a post type called "Sermons". I then add a meta box with some text fields and echo out the results onto the web page. But here's my problem. The first time when you add a "Sermon", it works fine and the meta box fields output correctly. However, when I try to edit one of the meta boxes and do not edit the others, (say after I closed the web browser I remembered that I needed to add something to the fields,) the fields that were not edited become blank and the content in them is erased...not good at all.

So, just to simplify this: the first time the meta boxes are filled they work fine. However, when editing the post for the second time, the fields that are not filled out, but left as they were, become blank upon saving the post.

Help...I'm not too much of a developer so I'm not exactly sure how to fix this...(it was hard enough getting the meta fields to work.)

(If you want the actual code used, please tell me and I will add is somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/rock-solid-wordpress-3-0-themes-using-custom-post-types/#div-comment-302050

Answer (score 0):

I've got a good tutorial on [adding WordPress Meta Boxes](http://farinspace.com/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-meta-box/) additionally check out my [WPalchemy Meta Box PHP Class](http://farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) which will help you create meta boxes with ease.